# Regex to allow letters and up to 3 numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a username entry on a form. I would like to make sure they're entering their username and not their student ID. Student ID's are all numbers. Usernames could be a combination of letters and a few numbers, but will never be all numbers.

This is what I'm using now:

```
!/^[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

How do I modify that so that it allows up to 3 numbers?  I found this snippet but don't know how to insert it into the code above (assuming this is the right approach).

```
[0-9]{1,3}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Tim

Comment: Why not simply test that the input isn't all numbers?

Comment: Your requirements are a bit too broad, are the digits mandatory? are the digits always consecutive? I suggest to show several examples (good and bad)

Comment: Do you mean "up to three consecutive numbers are allowed in a username"?

Comment: Use `/^(?!\d+$)[a-z\d]+$/i`, it will match any string consisting of 1+ letters/digits but is not all digits.

Comment: You could also try `/(.*[0-9]){4}/i` and if there is a match you have too many digits, otherwise you are fine.

Comment: Your question is too vague. "a combination of letters and a few numbers", does that mean __AB123__, __123AB__ and __1A2B3__ are all valid usernames? That's what we need to know before we can come up with a regex that matches them.

Comment: `!/^\d{1,3}$/i`

Comment: Thank you all for your input. It's been very helpful. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Tim I think what you're looking for is `/^(?!(?:\D*\d){4}$)[a-z\d]+$/`. This doesn't allow empty strings or any usernames with 4+ digits in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you want is `/^((?:.*\d.*){4,}|\d{1,})$/g`.

`^` Start of string anchor

`(?:.*\d.*){4,}` Match if 4 or more numbers are contained in the string

`|` Alternation

`\d{1,}` Match if there are only numbers in the string

`$` End of string anchor

Change `(?:.*\d.*){4,}` for `(?:[a-zA-Z]*\d.*){4,}` if you want to match letters only.

[Test it Here!](https://regexr.com/3j821)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that will match if you have more than 3 digits, so if you get a match, it is a bad Student name.

```js
var good = ["bill123", "n1n1n1", "n1", "nmnnnn"]
var bad = ["1234", "bill1234", "n1n1n1n1", "n1111"]

for (let g of good) {
  console.log(g.search('(.*[0-9]){4}'));
}

for (let b of bad) {
  console.log(b.search('(.*[0-9]){4}'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't super clear but what you've laid out isn't really specific enough for a good regular expression. If what you are checking for is "3 or less numbers total and not entirely numbers" then I would say first, check that the input is not all numbers by finding any letter `[a-z]` then you can count the number of numerals by doing `str.split(/\d/).length - 1` (or some other string character counting method)